# General Advice on the proof of inequalities

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inequality

I've got a pretty basic question that has been slightly confusing to me (I *kinda* understand this, but I  need some affirmation).

Basically, say I have an inequality $(2n+3)^2>4(n+1)(n+2)$, which, when both sides are expanded and like terms are collected and removed, you get $1>0$. But why does this result prove that the initial inequality is true?

Thanks

Comment: substracting the same thing from both sides of an inequality transforms it into an equivalent inequality. in your case what you do is substract $4(n+1)(n+2)$ from both sides

Comment: Does this mean that, since 1>0, then the previous inequality must also be true?

Comment: yes, because you've obtained it from your initial inequality using only operations which result in equivalent inequalities - that is the case using substractions or addition, but it wouldn't be so if you, for example, wanted to square both sides - that you cannot do

Comment: Technically, the previous inequality is true because when you _add_ $4(n+1)(n+2)$ to both sides of $1>0$ you produce the previous inequality. Things like squaring don't work this way because taking the square root doesn't necessarily give back the original value.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $f(n) = LHS - RHS$, i.e. $f(n) = (2n+3)^2 - 4(n+1)(n+2)$

Now when you simplfy the function you get $f(n) = 4n^2 - 4n^2 +12n -12n + 9 - 8 = 1$ i.e. $f(n) = 1$, so, $f(n) = (2n+3)^2 - 4(n+1)(n+2) = 1 > 0$ i.e. $LHS -RHS > 0$ so that  $LHS > RHS$